# Change dimension name in netcdf file with python

Tags: python, netcdf

Hi I want to edit some information in a NetCDF file, to give an example suppose that you have a ncdump of the file with the next info:

```
NetCDF dimension information:
 Name: lon
    size: 144
    type: dtype('float64')
 Name: lat
    size: 73
    type: dtype('float64')
 Name: time
    size: 29220
    type: dtype('float64')
NetCDF variable information:
 Name: rlut
    dimensions: (u'time', u'lat', u'lon')
    type: dtype('float32')
```

I want to change 'lon' for 'longitude'. I tried with:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
path="Here goes the file path"
f=Dataset(path,'r+')
f.renameDimension(u'lon',u'longitude')
f.close()
```

But after this when I tried to read the file again for doing something different the file doesn't work anymore.

Any help I will Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "read the file again for doing something different"? Is this using different software? This behavior is expected to work just as you tried, and if it doesn't, that's a bug. See the unit test here: https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/source/browse/trunk/test/tst_rename.py?r=1146 (Also, it just worked fine for me with ncdump when I just tried it)

Comment: When I say "read the file again for doing something different" I mean that the file after this procedure is corrupted, so it is not possible to do any with the file.

Comment: Then I would open an issue at: https://github.com/unidata/netcdf4-python/issues and if you could, post your datafile somewhere, because it should work just as you tried, and worked for me here.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks N1B4 for the suggestion of using NCO, it is a very good option for working and editing NetCDF files.

I want to post here a sketch of my solution for anyone that might be interested in modifying a NetCDF file using python and the netcdf4 library. The idea is to create a new NetCDF file importing the info from an existing file.

```
#First import the netcdf4 library
from netCDF4 import Dataset  # http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/

# Read en existing NetCDF file and create a new one
# f is going to be the existing NetCDF file from where we want to import data
# and g is going to be the new file.

f=Dataset('pathtoexistingfile','r') # r is for read only
g=Dataset('name of the new file','w') # w if for creating a file
                                      # if the file already exists it  
                                      # file will be deleted 


# To copy the global attributes of the netCDF file  

for attname in f.ncattrs():
    setattr(g,attname,getattr(f,attname))

# To copy the dimension of the netCDF file

for dimname,dim in f.dimensions.iteritems():
       # if you want to make changes in the dimensions of the new file
       # you should add your own conditions here before the creation of the dimension.
        g.createDimension(dimname,len(dim))


# To copy the variables of the netCDF file

for varname,ncvar in f.variables.iteritems():
       # if you want to make changes in the variables of the new file
       # you should add your own conditions here before the creation of the variable.
       var = g.createVariable(varname,ncvar.dtype,ncvar.dimensions)
       #Proceed to copy the variable attributes
       for attname in ncvar.ncattrs():  
          setattr(var,attname,getattr(ncvar,attname))
       #Finally copy the variable data to the new created variable
       var[:] = ncvar[:]


f.close()
g.close()
```

I hope that this might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use Python, I'd recommend NCO's `ncrename` function: http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncrename-netCDF-Renamer

```
ncrename -d lon,longitude sample_file.nc
```

Comment: I tried this option but when I read the file after this I get the error `RuntimeError: NetCDF: Invalid dimension ID or name`

Comment: Strange, is there a way for you to share the netcdf file?

Comment: I solved the problem creating a new NetCDF file importing the properties from the old one. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is quite an old post it might still be valuable to add this:

The indicated method by Ajaramillo did not work in my case because it was missing to rename also the variable name, not just the dimension name. This worked for me:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
path="Here goes the file path"
f=Dataset(path,'r+')
f.renameDimension(u'lon',u'longitude')
f.renameVariable(u'lon',u'longitude')
f.renameDimension(u'lat',u'latitude')
f.renameVariable(u'lat',u'latitude')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd also need to modify any references to the renamed dimension. E.g. your variable, rlut, which has a dimension of 'lon', which has been renamed to 'longitude'. Not sure if this can be done via in place editing. You may need to create a new copy of the file using:

```
createVariable('rlut', 'f4', ('time', 'lat', 'longitude')
```

Comment: I tried this option too but I get the error when I use the file. I guess it is a problem of the particular netcdf file I am using.