# edit an existing NetCDF / write a netcdf to the same name

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to edit netcdf datasets and save them back to the same filename (e.g. to change the attributes or change variable names in a dataset). e.g.:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3), coords={'x': ['a', 'b']}, dims=('x', 'y'))
data.to_netcdf('test.nc')

test_open=xr.open_dataset('test.nc')
test_open=test_open.rename({'__xarray_dataarray_variable__':'var'})
test_open.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

This gives a 'permission denied' error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"

Reading https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2887, it seems it's to do with the file being open, and I've also tried:

```
with xr.open_dataset('test.nc') as test_open:
    test_open=test_open.rename({'__xarray_dataarray_variable__':'var'})
    test_open.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

or

```
with xr.open_dataset('test.nc') as test_open:
    test_open=test_open.rename({'__xarray_dataarray_variable__':'var'})
test_open.to_netcdf('test.nc')
```

I often need to do this with large datasets so would rather not load the dataset into memory, although even if I do I sometimes get 'HDF5' errors.

I don't fully understand what is causing the problem here, can anyone explain? It seems like it must be a common problem to change metadata on a dataset without having to load or rename the dataset. I'm using the latest version of xarray, 0.16.1.

Comment: You can’t do this with xarray. I think you can with the netCDF library - not positive though. Xarray is really built around computation and doesn’t offer much support for in-place manipulation of netCDF encoded files.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61638623/3888719

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a go using netCDF. I thought xarray used netCDF so assumed they'd have similar functionality for reading/writing.

Comment: Even if it is necessary to load the dataset, is there a way to read a dataset 'filename', do something to it and write to the same name using xarray? This seems to work on some of my files but not others, but perhaps someone has a consistent way of doing this that will work on all files?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado although using the netCDF library directly could be fine, opening and closing files including proper handling of the file pointers seems pretty basic stuff to me, so why shouldn't a full featured library like xarray be capable of that?

Comment: if you consider modifying netCDF attributes in place to be one of the features, then xarray isn't "fully featured" :) this has been a user request for a long time and the core team doesn't seem interested in supporting it. I agree with their call - this is a data-format-specific request that is handled just fine by python-netCDF4 and other client libraries and doesn't fit the lazy loading computing model xarray uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html

"It is possible to append or overwrite netCDF variables using the mode='a' argument. When using this option, all variables in the dataset will be written to the original netCDF file, regardless if they exist in the original dataset."

In the python NetCDF library I use:

> netCDF4.Dataset(file,'r+',clobber=True).

to edit attributes and variables in place.  Perhaps `clobber` could be passed to xarray's `**kwargs` which get passed to the underlying NetCDF4 engine.